# Google Chrome adds extra div?

Tags: google-chrome

Hi guys I don't know about you but I found in ubuntu Google Chrome adds a useless div with z-index:-1 at the bottom of body in HTML. I can see that at any web page. And that div covered the whole page which makes elements with z-index less than -1 don't work.

EDIT: So it seems like because of some plugins I installed. Not chrome's bug.

Comment: I see no such div. However, it might be a bug. I am on Chromium nightly, so if you're on G-Chrome's Dev or Canary build you might be seeing a bug. I suggest you report it if someone already hasn't.

Comment: Or it might be a plugin which causes this.

Comment: You are right. It's a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some plugin that is doing this considering you see this behaviour on every page.