# What is this strange div in Google-Chrome?

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome

If I go on any page, with the latest version of google chrome and open Developer tools, there is this strange div that is the first element of the `<body>` in all HTML pages:

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px; z-index: 9999999; ">
    <div style="position: fixed; top: 100%; height: 0px; ">
        <div style="position: relative; ">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is there on every page I browse to, including this page on Stack Overflow. I'm wondering if anyone else sees this, or knows why it's there?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887966/google-chrome-adds-extra-div.  They blame it on a plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you must be running some extension that's adding it. I don't see that with the latest Chrome at my end (without extensions installed).

Comment: Oh you're probably right! I did install a bunch of extensions the other day just to try them out. Let me see if I can find it.

Comment: Yes, I found it. It was an extension called `jsshell` and as soon as I disabled it the div was removed. Thanks for your help, I was really confused for a bit there and it was messing with my expected results from `document.body.firstChild` in Javascript, haha.

Comment: @Paul: LOL, yeah, it would. (I think I'd've probably added it at the *end* of body, if I were writing that. And only when activated by the keypress...)

Answer (score 3):

Might be part of some extension you are using with Chrome? I don't see it either. Try disabling your extensions one by one to find out which one is injecting that code.

Answer (score 3):

Extensions may modify the source code of webpages before loading, so, yeah, it probably is one you have installed.